# Match an order number with combination of alphabetical characters and numbers?

Tags: python, regex

I have this string that goes:

`BOL# : 1113QTZV2 11 44`.

`11 44` being dummy text that shouldn't be matched with.

I want to match only `1113QTZV2`. Now, sometimes the last character can be either some letter or some number. For example (only difference is last letter), `1113QTZV2`or `1113QTZVA`.

I tried this:

`[\dA-Z]*` but it still matches every thing. Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: It works for me, how are you matching it?

Comment: It matches everything when I only need 1113QTZV2. I want to ignore the rest and only focus on that one.

Comment: Any problem with `your_string.split()[2]`?

Comment: @mshsayem I thought of splitting the string but I passed up that decision so as to not hard code it too much.

Comment: This pattern should serve you well I think: `\d{4}[A-Z]{4,5}\d?`. It works with the examples but I'm not sure if it's general enough for the rest of occurrences.

Comment: @dearprudence does your code has some fixed length interval? Or a minimal length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your the code you want to match has fixed length, you can use the pattern `\w{9}`.

```
import re

code = 'BOL# : 1113QTZV2 11 44'
print(re.search(r'\w{9}', code).group()) # 1113QTZV2
```

Comment: Ahh, that's why you asked. Thanks! What if the length isn't fixed and could be less/more than 9 sometimes?

Comment: You can provide an interval. By example, if you know the code is from 8 to 10 character, use `\w{8,10}`. If you just know it's more than 9, you could use `\w{9,}`